# Understanding mongodb md5 key in GridFS files collection

Tags: mongodb

Please explain the usage of md5 key in GridFS files collection.

In mongodb [GridFS reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/) it says: "An MD5 hash returned from the filemd5 API. This value has the String type.", What is need for this hash ?

Answer (score 3):

I tryied to understand that too some weeks ago, and i still have some doubt, but i report to you what i had read [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.2.3/file.GridFS.html)

> A kind of safe mode is built into the GridFS specification. When you
>   save a file, and MD5 hash is created on the server. If you save the
>   file in safe mode, an MD5 will be created on the client for comparison
>   with the server version. If the two hashes don't match, an exception
>   will be raised.

I guess it's a kind of check to see if the file is being update correctly[?]

edit: found that short sentence too, in official mongodb site, give a look
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/filemd5/

Answer (score 0):

I use the `md5` field to make sure I update the file only if it was changed without having to fetch the whole file from the DB and compare it.

I do `db.col_name.find({id: myid}, {md5: 1})` so I fetch only the `md5` field, I calculate the md5 of the new file, and update only if needed.

Fetching the whole file and making full data comparison could be very slow and traffic expensive.